# Is it possible to use a namespace or equivalent in an implementation file to avoid having to prefix every function with the class name?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a class :

```
class Foo{

public:

void someFunc():

}
```

Then in the implementation I need to do:

```
void Foo::someFunc(){
//My implementation.
}
```

Is there some way I can avoid having to prefix each function with `Foo::`, by using namespaces or something ? (just to save on typing.. no other reason).

EDIT: I don't see why this is down voted. If there was a C++ feature to structure code so we don't have to type as much, its actually worth knowing - similar to using the "Using" keyword so we don't have to prefix the namespace repeatedly...

EDIT: @PeteBecker Typing less is normally more maintainable (there is less code to maintain) - which is why we organise code into into constructs that allow us to share and reuse code. Correctness is not necessarily related to typing - but the less time you spend typing, the more time you have to spend on focusing on the idea or product, and whether your code is "correct". Prefixing a namespace or classname each time you refer to an object, does not make your code any more or less correct, but simply just takes time, and there is no reason to waste time doing things that are unnecessary. Which is why we have the "using" keyword for namespaces, so we won't have to type namespaces each time (I mentioned this earlier). So just like we have a "using" keyword for namespaces, I was asking if there was a way to do this for classes.

Comment: No, there is no way.

Comment: Your IDE should be able to automatically generate the `void Foo::someFunc()` part for you.

Comment: @cpplearner I would prefer to avoid anything relying on the IDE, but instead just use the features the standard includes...

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Typing is typically a tiny portion of the time spent developing code that is correct and maintainable.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sure, there's the time-wasted-typing aspect (which is nontrivial; why do you think we use fancy editors and IDEs?), but it's also ugly and, in my opinion, not particularly helpful for maintaining correct and maintainable code.

Comment: @PeteBecker To answer your question, I updated my question since there isn't enough space in the comments..

Comment: Re the edit: no, I don't spend time typing. I type, and it's pretty much subconscious; it happens while I'm thinking about what the code is doing and what it should look like. Typing simply is not a bottleneck for any reasonably competent programmer. There are much more significant process improvements to focus on.

Comment: @PeteBecker You are missing the entire point - any typing which can be avoided is a waste of time. You are also incorrect about your statement "I don't spend time typing". Does your code magically appear instantaneously ? You do spend time typing, although you may not be aware of it, or concerned about the time you spend typing, and even if you do type at 200 words per minute, if there is a way to type even less, you can get even more done quicker. By having to type less, you have more time, to focus on other things. I think my point is clear, and have nothing more to say about that.

Comment: @PeteBecker Also, whether there is any benefit to typing more or less, is going off point from my question,  - whether there is some way in C++, similar to the "using" keyword, but for classes. I would prefer to end this discussion on the merits of typing less, as it is taking away from my question, which has to do with the features of c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you put the implementation directly in the header file.

Comment: But won't that slow down compilation, because then its included in every file that includes it ... ? I thought it was better to have separate compilation units....

Comment: @John Yes, that will slow down compilation and may have other disadvantages as well (though it could potentially improve optimization if you're not using link-time optimization). Yes, this is an annoying shortcoming of the language.

Comment: I feel like this isn't quite the right explanation. One must put the implementation directly in the _class body_.

Comment: @erip Can you explain ? I think I might be misunderstanding what you're saying...

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what something that should be used but still a solution:

```
#define a Foo::
void a someFunc() ...
```

Comment: It has some undesirable side effects - for example, it interferes with variables named "a" in other files... otherwise it "works"... But points for creativity! haha. I wish we could just dump all the methods within a block which had the name of the class.... I guess its not possible to do it elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't with classes, but with namespaces you can:

test.h:

```
namespace Test {
    void someFunc();
};
```

test.cpp:

```
namespace Test {
    void someFunc() {
        std::cout << "someFunc called" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Sure, limited usefulness but it'll be good to know if you ever need to put some classes in a namespace